# How to extract a image (vector graphic) from a surface EPS plot with GaussView?

Tags: computational-chemistry, density-functional-theory

I am quiet new to this field of chemistry. I work with GaussView and I created a surface plot for my molecule with the cube and surface generator. This works very well. Now I like to save and copy this image of my molecule with its surface. My favorite file type whould be a vector graphic type (eps or svg).
I don not know how. I tried the option with File -> Save Image. When I choose vector graphic as type I just get the structur of my molecule but not the surface (as well as a error message...). When I choose all the other file types I get nothing in the file just a black screen.
Where is my mistake? What do I constantly wrong? I see a lot of these plots in publications... I just want this plot for my PowerPoint...

I hope someone of you got a godd tip for me, thanks!